# How do I write "piano style" cadences?

Tags: theory, voice-leading, cadence

I'm currently undertaking the AMEB theory grades. I'm up to grade 4 and am working on different types of cadences but I STILL don't understand how "piano style" (the one with the bass note in the bass and the other 3 notes in the treble) cadences work, how to write them, or the general rules of them. I seem to almost ALWAYS get the answer wrong. Every time I go to Google it, I can't find anything relevant because I guess the words 'piano' + 'style' put together aren't very distinct. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: “Piano style” sounds like a term specific to your teacher / school. It isn’t a standard musical term. Talk to your teacher about your confusion.

Comment: also know as "Pianoforte Style" cadences

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the term you're looking for is **keyboard style**. To help your Internet searches, try "keyboard style voice leading."

In keyboard style, you write three-voice chords in the upper staff and a single bass voice in the lower staff; this is an attempt to mimic a standard keyboard texture:

[image]

This is in contrast to **chorale style**, sometimes called *SATB style*, where you mimic the soprano–alto–tenor–bass orchestration of a choir. Oftentimes chorale style simply moves one voice of keyboard style by an octave:

[image]

---

As for rules for writing cadences, it's a bit too broad to pinpoint exactly what you're asking, but here are some general rules:

- The leading tone (scale-degree 7) *must resolve up by step to tonic* when it is in an outer voice (soprano or bass). If it is in an inner voice (alto or tenor), it can move down to scale-degree 5 (or, more rarely, up to scale-degree 3). Not knowing the AMEB system, I recommend resolving all leading tones up to tonic.
- Since scale-degree 5 is present in both the V and I chords, just keep scale-degree 5 where it is (except for the bass, which will tend to move to scale-degree 1).
- If you have a chordal seventh, this chordal seventh *must resolve down by step*. In a V7 chord, this will be scale-degree 4 moving down to scale-degree 3.
- The remaining scale degree, scale-degree 2, can move up to scale-degree 3 or down to scale-degree 1.

The above are just broad tips assuming you're looking at V(7)–I cadences. But most importantly, the term **keyboard style** should help you access the necessary AMEB information online. Best of luck!

Comment: It is worth noting that for keyboard/pianoforte style:  the notes in the treble staff must all be within one octave (so you can reach all the keys with one hand)